# Wrong keyword style when using multiple languages in listings

Tags: listings, bugs

With this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{%
  language=[AlLaTeX]TeX,
  alsolanguage=MetaPost,
  texcsstyle=\color{blue},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
 $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

the `\sum` is not colored. But, if I replace `MetaPost` by `pstricks`, `\sum` turns into blue.

Someone could help me and explain the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `listings` package documentation:

> Bug: `texcs`... interferes with other keyword lists. If, for
>   example, `emph` contains the word `foo`, then the control 
>   sequence `\foo` will show up in `emphstyle`.

Based on this I tried to declare `MetaPost` first and `TeX` second, and it worked.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{%
    language=MetaPost,
    alsolanguage=[AlLaTeX]TeX,
    texcsstyle=\color{blue},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
    $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$.
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

You can also use a starred variant of `texcsstyle` to also highlight the backslash:

```
texcsstyle=*\color{blue}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: thanks. I'll try this afternoon :)